# Pass keyboard events to child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, keyboard-events

See this simple modal component:

```
Vue.component('modal-content', {
  template: `
      <div class="modal">
         ...
      </div>
  `,

  props: ['title'],

});
```

How can I control keyboard press from the components that use it (parents)?

If I use @keyup.esc event then it does not have any effect:

```
<portal to="modal-wrap">
  <modal-content @keyup.esc="doSomething">
  </modal-content>
</portal>
```

If I put @keyup.esc in the modal-content component on the DIV then it works, but that's no use to me because I need to call the `doSomething` function which exists in the parent component

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason your code is not working is because your you are trying to listen to a native browser event - which is not emitted by Vue, but by the DOM itself.

To react to these type of events you have to attach your listener to an actual `HTMLElement` - not a vue component. Since this is a common issue, vue provides a simple modifier that automatically attaches the eventlistener to the underlying `HTMLElement`: the `.native` modifier.

#### Try it like this

```
<portal to="modal-wrap">
  <modal-content @keyup.esc.native="doSomething">
  </modal-content>
</portal>
```

You can find further information in vues [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on)

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this
in your doSomething function:

```
onClickButton (event) {
      this.$emit('clicked', 'someValue')
}
```

And in you parent component do this:

```
<template>
   <parent-component @clicked="handleClick"></parent-component>
</template>
```

For more info check this:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events

And this:

https://medium.com/js-dojo/component-communication-in-vue-js-ca8b591d7efa

Answer (score 1):

Use **refs** ([Accessing Child Component Instances & Child Elements](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements))

```
<modal-content @keyup.esc="doSomething" ref="modal">
```

then inside the doSomething method:

`this.$refs.modal.close();`

presuming you have a `close()` method in the modal-content component.

---

You could also pass a [prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html), like you are doing with `title`:

`<modal-content @keyup.esc="modalIsOpen = false" :modalIsOpen="modalIsOpen">`

```
Vue.component('modal-content', {
  template: `
      <div class="modal" :class="{show: modalIsOpen}">
         ...
      </div>
  `,
  props: ['title' 'modalIsOpen'],
  //...
});
```

Comment: You are assuming I only need Esc to close it, but I also want to hook other keys, like Enter, and assign them to different buttons inside the modal..

Comment: then for different actions sent different events